# Positioning element outside viewport for css animation without trigering scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, animation, viewport

I'm creating simple css animation of text sliding to the page from right.
I'm using  jQuery to trigger animation by adding a class to element.
But the start position must be outside viewport and that triggers bottom scrollbar to appear. How to prevent that?
This is relevant css fragment

```
h2{
position:absolute;
right:-500px;
top:190px;
font-size:45px;
.transition(3s,  linear);
}
h2.centered{
top:88px;
left:30%;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a fiddle reproducing the issue ?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on the container will solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable horizontal scrollbar due to a DIV with position:absolute which is outside of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111823/disable-horizontal-scrollbar-due-to-a-div-with-positionabsolute-which-is-outsid)

Comment: @Lord_JABA See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I'm guessing you are triggering the change in class with some form of javascript of jQuery.
The trick here is to set:

```
  overflow-x: hidden;
```

on the body of your page (although this will remove scrollbars entirely). The better option however would be to apply "overflow-x: hidden" to a container div within your body.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vnvet/2/

Comment: think it should be it, but I will see tomorrow morning. my mistake was I apply it to text itself, not to a container.