# How to make a logo slide in from off screen when the page loads in?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to design my first website after learning `HTML`, `CSS` and basic `JavaScript`. One problem that I have encountered is, that it is almost impossible to find out how to make something slide in from off screen when the page loads initially.

An example of this is on https://rinodeboer.com/ but i can't find any resources that teach you how to do this.

Can someone please help explain how to make a logo slide in from off the screen onto the screen when the site loads. Thanks.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
}

header {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
}

.basket {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.NavMenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

col-2 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #563434;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo-holder">
        <img src="..\Images\Logo\Logo Draft 1\Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul id="MenuItems" class="NavMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="..\Images\cart.png" alt="Basket" class="basket" />
      <img src="..\Images\PlaceHolders\menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <h1>Dragon Ball Accounts On Sale Now!<br /> Limited Time Only</h1>
        <p>Geting Dragon Ball Z accounts are cheaper than ever before for limited time only<br /> Don't miss this golden opportunity and buy now</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Explore Now &#8594;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="..\Images\dragon_ball_z.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. You don't need JS or JQuery for it at all. You can use css-animation for it. Alternativly use `@keyframes`. Unfortunatly SO is not a tutorial, guide or forum. It is expected that you have done own research efford and at least tried to solve the issue on your own. As such please try to solve it with css-animation and ask again if you get stuck and provide a code of your attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positioning element outside viewport for css animation without trigering scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426996/positioning-element-outside-viewport-for-css-animation-without-trigering-scrollb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a CSS animation and `@keyframe` rule. You can add a class to the parent and make its position ***relative***, then make the image ***absolute*** so you can control the *positioning* of the logo using ***left***.

Then create an animation in css and give it a name `slidein` `animation: slidein 1.5s ease-in-out;`, set the duration and ease. Then set the @keyframe to create a keyframe tween using the animation name you named it `slidein`.

You can control any percentage of the keyframe rule using a percentage or keywords `from` and `to`. [@keyframes ~ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

```css
.logoParent img {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slidein 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -1000px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
}

header {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
}

.basket {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.NavMenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

col-2 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #563434;
}

.logo-holder {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.logoParent img {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: slidein 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.logoParent {
  top: -50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-holder img {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slideintop 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -1000px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideintop {
  0% {
    top: -1000px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo-holder">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.assets.neo4j.com/wp-content/uploads/stack-overflow-logo-json-data.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul id="MenuItems" class="NavMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="..\Images\cart.png" alt="Basket" class="basket" />
      <img src="..\Images\PlaceHolders\menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <h1>Dragon Ball Accounts On Sale Now!<br /> Limited Time Only</h1>
        <p>Geting Dragon Ball Z accounts are cheaper than ever before for limited time only<br /> Don't miss this golden opportunity and buy now</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Explore Now &#8594;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="logoParent col-2">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.assets.neo4j.com/wp-content/uploads/stack-overflow-logo-json-data.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using css , jquery *It may've other ways to be done but this is my solution*

- **In css** you need two classes one for `transform: translateY` and one for `transition-duration
- **In js** you need to loop through the elements with the transform class to remove the class from it to make the effect.. use `setTimeout` to slide the element asynchronous

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slide_to_down , .slide_to_up').each(function(i){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $this.removeClass('slide_to_down slide_to_up');
    } , i * 200);
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
}

header {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
}

.basket {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.NavMenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

col-2 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ff523b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #563434;
}

/* classes for the effect ////////*/
.slide_to_down{
   transform : translateY(-400%);
   opacity : 0;
}
.slide_to_up{
   transform : translateY(200%);
   opacity : 0;
}
.trans{
  transition : transform 1s;
}
/*////////////////////////////////*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo-holder">
        <img src="..\Images\Logo\Logo Draft 1\Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo slide_to_down trans" />
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul id="MenuItems" class="NavMenu">
          <li class="slide_to_down trans"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="slide_to_down trans"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li class="slide_to_down trans"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="..\Images\cart.png" alt="Basket" class="basket" />
      <img src="..\Images\PlaceHolders\menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 slide_to_up trans">
        <h1>Dragon Ball Accounts On Sale Now!<br /> Limited Time Only</h1>
        <p>Geting Dragon Ball Z accounts are cheaper than ever before for limited time only<br /> Don't miss this golden opportunity and buy now</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Explore Now &#8594;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="..\Images\dragon_ball_z.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Notes:

- Don't forget to add jquery liberary
- For any element you want to add this effect to it just add classes `class="slide_to_down trans"` to slide to down OR `class="slide_to_up trans"` to slide to up