# How to avoid horizontal scroll bar with transitioned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple elements in which I am using `transform:translate` to add a slide in transition effect. This is working great. The issue I am having is since the elements are off the screen initially, scroll bars are appearing until the element transforms and slides over.

I am using waypoints for the scroll point and I have seen other scenarios (slidein from off the page) that the scroll bar does not appear.

How can I ensure the scroll bar does not appear with these transitioned elements on my page?

The `active` class is added to `phone-slide` when the waypoint is reached.

```
#phone-slide {
    width: 65%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
}
#phone-slide.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your problem using a codepen or jsfiddle for us to look at what is actually happening?

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to position `phone-slide` inside an absolute positioned div with hidden overflow. This div can have width and height equal to the page dimensions and the content inside it will be truncated if it goes beyond with no scrollbars.

See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111823/disable-horizontal-scrollbar-due-to-a-div-with-positionabsolute-which-is-outsid) solution by **Jacob Ewing**

Another accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308257/positionabsolute-causes-horizontal-scrollbar)